# Creating simple sprites in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics

Im realatively new to programming, I want to make a fairly simple game in visual studio for a school project; At this stage I need to create a simple sprite of a ship which can rotate and move in the direction it's facing, I already made a movement engine but I am stuck at making the sprite itself. What is the simplest method of making the sprite, preferably without the use of third party software.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Note that winforms is really limited wrt animation

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've never tried to program a game in visual studio and I don't have an answer to that But Instead, I have an easier suggestion which is to learn the basics of unity game engine which shouldn't take more than 3 hours or so but the possibilities unity will give is much better than visual studio's because unity is specialized in games while visual studio is specialized in programs, so if your game is as simple as you are describing then I would highly recommend that you give unity a try, and btw unity uses c# as it's programming language so you shouldn't find any difficulties with the programming side.

cheers !